# Value is not an array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm working on some C homework for class and I've been running into issues using arrays. Here is a sample of one of my functions that's having an error.

```
void multiply(int a, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        a[i] = a[i] * 5;
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It returns the `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` on lines 5 & 6 when I call for `a[i]`. I have `a` as an array with size 10, but each time I try and call an individual value in the array it doesn't want to work. I've tried searching it but none of the solutions really seems to work.

Comment: `int a` is not an array. In is an `int`.

Comment: The word "vector" in the error message refers to a gcc-specific C language extension, not to C++'s `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your function to:

```
void multiply(int * a, int size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function header to:

```
void multiply(int* a, int size)
```

Othewise the function thinks `a` is an int not an int array

Comment: Actually that makes `a` a pointer, not an array. The pointer points to the first element of some array object, but it is not itself an array. (The code change is correct; I'm quibbling about your description of it.)